# Report Builder - AutoRefresh using TextBox Value

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to allow the user to set the AutoRefresh time, I've tried using the following expression:

```
=(ReportItems!txt_Update.Value)*60
```

But I get the following error message:

> The AutoRefresh expression for the report ‘body’ refers to the report
>   item ‘txt_Update’.  Report item expressions can only refer to other
>   report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping
>   scope. Letters in the names of report items must use the correct case.

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer from the outer element (which is the report itself in this case) to the inner element (txt_Update) because the inner element can be rendered many times in the session.

Instead of the text box you can use a report parameter. Try to add a report parameter of type integer, e.g. called RefreshInterval, and use the following expression for the AutoRefresh property:

```
=Parameters!RefreshInterval.Value
```

Best regards,

~Alexey

Answer (score 0):

You can do as your project model or template model to autorefresh.

http://ucodia.fr/2011/10/advanced-reporting-services-part1-rdl-object-model/